# css float issue ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I've had a quick butchers for an answer for this problem, but I'm in a bit of a rush and couldnt find an applicable one. This page:
http://rock-chick.com/products/17/groovy-chick
Looks fine in FF but in IE7 it looks completely wrong even though all constraints are fine.

What could be the problem causing this?

Cheers

Comment: A not safe for work - NSFW - warning would have been nice.

Comment: Which part of the page are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 does this with floated elements when the widths are just a little too close for it's comfort. I fix it just by setting the width of the offending floater just a few pixels smaller.